# Bulk Insert takes 4x as long on first operation of the day

Tags: sql-server-2005, bulkinsert

I do Bulk Inserts into a table with about 14 million rows at fiver minute increments during a 7 hour period during the day.  These inserts take somewhere between 9-14 secs.  However, the first insert always takes about 40 secs.  Anyone know what SQL Server 2005 would be doing differently on the first insert into a table for that day?

From what I've read I should probably use the SqlBulkCopy class instead of just using a bulk insert in a stored procedure.  Is that that the general consensus?

Comment: What happens between the Nth and the (N+1)th load of the day? What happens between the Last load and the First load of the next day that differs from this routine? (Is the system just sitting idle? For how long? No overnight maintenance or processes being run?)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a truncate/shrink job that runs overnight?

If so then this means that your first operation will cause the file to grow, hence a wait while this happens.

Answer (score 0):

A maintenance job that shrinks the database in the night may be the culprit. In such a case, database file will grow on your first insert and that will cause a delay on the insert.

Also, if you are doing large inserts, consider disabling and re-enabling indices.